# Google Cloud Vision API 400 Invalid JSON Payload

Tags: php, json, api, curl, google-cloud-vision

I have entered all of the required fields as they write on protocol section in https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-labels#vision-label-detection-protocol as i wrote my code below. But, still it return 400 error.

```
<?php
if(!isset($googleapikey)){
    include('settings.php');
}
function vision($query){
    global $googleapikey;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key='.$googleapikey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $result;
}

$vdata = array();
$vdata['requests'][0]['image']['source']['imageUri'] = 'https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/images/ferris-wheel.jpg';
$vdata['requests'][0]['features'][0]['type'] = 'LABEL_DETECTION';
echo vision(json_encode($vdata));
?>
```

Comment: Try `json_encode($vdata, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`. By default, `json_encode()` escapes forward slashes (such as in `http://`) which might not be compatible with the Google API

Comment: It's still return 400 error

Comment: http://andra.systems/google/vision.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only error in the request to Cloud Vision API is that you are not setting propery the HTTP Header field *Content-type: application/json*, because you are not assigning it to the right variable (you are pointing to `$curl` instead of `$ch`):

```
// Insread of this:
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
// Use this:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
```

The error shown when running your old code was the one below, which indicated that the query was not understanding the content data as JSON.

```
Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"requests\":[{\"image\":{\"source\":{\"imageU ri\":\"https://cloud' could not be found in request message.
```

---

As a side note, let me recommend you the [Client Libraries for Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/libraries), which have some [nice documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.54.0/vision/visionclient) and can make your life easier when working with some of the APIs in Google Cloud Platform from a script. In this case, you would not need to force a `curl` command, and you could achieve the same results with a much simple (and understandable) code, such as:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Vision\VisionClient;

$projectId = '<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>';
$vision = new VisionClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

$fileName = 'https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/images/ferris-wheel.jpg';
$image = $vision->image(file_get_contents($fileName), ['LABEL_DETECTION']);
$labels = $vision->annotate($image)->labels();

echo "Labels:\n";
foreach ($labels as $label) {
    echo $label->description() . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh my god, that's was a liitle mistake! Thank you so much!